# Congratulations, Philosophy is graduating!

Tags: discussion

It's a big day. You've been cleared for graduation by the Stack Exchange Community Team! Philosophy met our threshold for [graduation-worthy sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) and after a review, the Community Team determined that you're good to go. Reaching 'mature community' status is a big milestone, and you should be very proud.

What does this mean exactly? Graduation works in two phases. Starting today, you'll receive the following benefits:

- You will soon have an election for community-voted moderators - yours is scheduled for July 25th, which is three weeks from now.
- You will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name
- You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network
- You will soon be able to select your own community ads. These should go up either today or tomorrow.

The site will still receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege. It's no secret that our backlog for site designs is long, so instead of making you wait to receive all the parts of graduation at once, we wanted to [give you the things we could give](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation) you now. We think we've hammered out most of the bugs in the process, but there are still likely to be some left -  so if you come across anything out of place, please report it on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) using the [graduating-sites] tag.

This site has reached this point because of your generous contributions. Together, you've created a valuable resource that helps people. Congratulations on all you've accomplished.

Comment: Wow! Awesome!! :)

Comment: @Bookend we've been at or above all the thresholds before, fairly recently

Comment: @Bookend We're pretty sure this is a summer lull, the passage of thresholds was a few weeks back.

Comment: Gotta say, I never thought this would happen. Woo-hoo!

Comment: This is great news! I'm glad to see this is finally happening. :)

Comment: Thanks to all who have contributed to the maturing of the community.

Comment: When will we have the "full design"? The site still looks as it used to look, without the beta.

Comment: @Gabriel: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our Community Managers from a few weeks ago: [Custom Philosophy SE design and logo - Information gathering](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5314/31765) :)