# When will Philosophy.stackexchange get a custom frontpage?

Tags: discussion, design

Are we still on beta? Most sites of the network have a custom design, which they got when they were out of beta.

Comment: Maybe we should be patient -- the queue is probably pretty long! :) But I'm sure we could start a thread with design ideas, aesthetic considerations, etc...

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our Community Managers from earlier today: [Custom Philosophy SE design and logo - Information gathering](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5314/31765) :)

Comment: Update: [Your new site design is live!](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5365/31765)

Answer (score 4):

Graduation and design [have been made independent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260754/205264). We graduated [in summer 2016](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3193/2953). As far as I know, there is no public design queue. But, you could have a look at [all sites ordered by traffic](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic). If I were SE, I would give high-traffic sites higher priority to get a custom design. And, sadly, there are still several higher-traffic sites without custom design. So, we'll probably just have to wait a bit.

Comment: There is a Meta.SE feature request to [give graduated sites a different theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/265813/191265) to set them apart from beta sites before they get a custom theme of their own. Even just changing the color scheme of the beta site would go a long way towards making them seem different.